# Read data from file and then working witch them. Converting string to float

Tags: c++, string, file

I have problem, but I don't know how fix it. Could someone help me?
Problem. In text file

```
1. 20.20
2. 3
```

I want to take data from file, and use it. My code:

```
int main() 
{
  string tp;
  float data_1 = 0, data_2 = 0, total = 0;

  std::fstream file;
  file.open("text.txt", ios::in);

  std::getline(file, tp);
  data_1 = std::stof(tp);

  std::getline(file, tp);
  data_2 = std::stof(tp);

  total = dat_1 * data_2;
  cout << "Total: " << total << endl;
}
```

In the program total is not 60.60, but it need be. Where is problem?

Comment: What's up with the text file? Are those line numbers? Does the file actually contain a number at the start of each line? Or is it a just a formatting issue on SO? Also: What output do you get? Did you attempt to use a debugger? If not it's a great opportunity to learn how to use one.

Comment: Do you really want `60,60`, not `60.60`?

Comment: Also your `text.txt` really contain `1.` and `2.`?

Comment: In the text file is 2 line. First line is 20.20 and second line 3. And I want get 60.60.

Comment: what total[sic,it's a product not a total] did you get?

Comment: Total is data_1 * data_2. If data_1 is 12.30 and data_2 7 then total should be 16.1. data_1 always will be float type, but data_2 int type

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `dat_1` is not declared and it should be `data_1`.

Then, you can use `std::fixed` to have it let specify the number of digits after dot and `std::setprecision` to specify the number of digits.

```
cout << "Total: " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << total << endl;
```

References:

- [std::fixed, std::scientific, std::hexfloat, std::defaultfloat - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)
- [std::setprecision - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

If you really want `60,60`, not `60.60`, printed, you can use [`std::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) to change the character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
using std::ios;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(){
    float total = 60.60;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << total << endl;
    std::string str = ss.str();
    std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), '.', ',');
    cout << "Total: " << str << endl;
}
```

Comment: No I want get 60.60. But in the text file could be write other number.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{
    std::string tp;
    float data_1 = 0, data_2 = 0, total = 0;
    std::ifstream file("text.txt");

    std::getline(file, tp);
    data_1 = std::stof(tp);
    std::getline(file, tp);
    data_2 = std::stof(tp);
    total = data_1 * data_2; // you wrote dat_1 instead of data_1
    std::cout << total << std::endl;
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: In the program I got error. error: 'stof' is not a member of 'std' it is at lines where written data_1 = std::stof(tp);